# Cast date to char in select - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I got to query some especific fields and now I need to convert the date to char in the select. In oracle goes like this:

```
SELECT title,
  to_char(created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd') created_at,
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (my_id LIKE '1')
```

My Rails query is:

```
SomeModel.where("my_id like ? ", some_id).select("title, to_char(created_at,'yyyy-mm-dd') created_at")
```

The Oracle query will return a date like '2013-01-01' but the Rails query seems not to be working it returns '2013-01-01T00:00:00-07:00'

It is possible that I'm missing something but I just don't know what. Also I know that I can format this in the view or some place else but I need it this way, in the SQL query.

Comment: `SomeModel.where("my_id like ? ", some_id).first.created_at.to_date` will turn the DateTime (= Date + Time) into a simple Date (no time associated). Then use `.strftime('YYYY-mm-dd')` to output it as you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the query with:

```
SomeModel.where("my_id like ? ", some_id).select("title, DATE(created_at) created_at")
```

You will see record as `[#<SomeModel title: "Foo" created_at: "2013-01-01 00:00:00", #..]`
Please note that it is completely fine. It is an ActiveRecord object and `created_at` is a DateTime field for that model, so no matter how you modify the query, it will still show it in `DateTime` fashion.

If you changed the query with something like 
`..select("title, DATE(created_at) created_at_date")`, then you will get the returned objects as:
`[#<SomeModel title: "Foo", #..]`. 
Again, this is completely fine too, named column `created_at_date` doesn't exist in the model, so these objects won't show them, though if you make a query as :    `result.first.created_at_date` #=> `"2013-01-01"`, which is exactly what you want.

Hope it clears how it works. :)

Comment: awesome!.. I didn't understand at the beggining your explaination but by changing as you mentioned the column name I get what I wanted. 
  SomeModel.where("my_id like ? ", some_id).select("title, to_char(created_at,'yyyy-mm-dd') created_at_date")

Comment: this DATE(created_at) helped me to cast date out created_at.thanx